# argument exception was unhandled in Lightswitch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

Argument exception error is thrown at the following code. It's a simple code but I'm new to c#.

```
 partial void PrintDocLetter1_CanExecute(ref bool result)
    {
        if (this.PatientsMasterItem.EligibileToParticipate != true)
        {


         this.FindControl("Print Doc Letter1").IsReadOnly = true;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this.FindControl("PrintDocLetter1").IsReadOnly = true;